# How to Configure vcluster to Use Internal Docker Registry Certificates?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm setting up a vcluster instance and I want it to use images from an internal Docker registry available at `docker-registry.docker-registry:5000`. On regular Kubernetes nodes, I usually configure this by placing the registry certificates in /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-registry.docker-registry:5000/ca.crt. However, I'm not sure how to configure vcluster to utilize these certificates. Can someone provide guidance on how to configure vcluster to use internal Docker registry certificates?

Additional Details:

```
- I'm using vcluster for my virtual Kubernetes clusters.
- The certificates for the internal Docker registry are typically stored in /etc/docker/certs.d/docker-registry.docker-registry:5000/ca.crt on regular Kubernetes nodes.
- I need assistance in configuring vcluster to utilize these certificates for accessing the internal Docker registry.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [TkgServiceConfiguration](https://theithollow.com/2021/09/22/configure-a-private-registry-for-tanzu-kubernetes-clusters/) to configure vcluster to use your internal Docker registry certificates.

This approach leverages a `TkgServiceConfiguration` resource within the Supervisor cluster to configure trust for the internal registry's certificate authority (CA).

Comment: I believe there might be a bit of confusion here. My question isn't about vSphere; rather, it pertains to vCluster: https://www.vcluster.com/